# Scope attribute in jsp

Tags: jsp, javabeans

My project architecture is the following structure .

Home page --> `getuserdata` (jsp page) -->  `printuserdata` jsp page)

`getuserdata` and  `printuserdata` are jsp pages and uses the java bean to get and print the data.

In  `getuserdata` I use scope as session and in next one scope is page . My Question is in both pages scope should be session ? if so why ?

I think I should go in details of jsp scope .. Can any one suggest any link?

Answer (score 0):

When you use bean in jsp, it will search in the sequence of application, session, request and page scopes.

So, if you want to share data across two jsp pages, you should go with the session scope in both pages for that bean.